# Weighted random in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have three employees: John, Ashley and Mark. During the day we keep receiving jobs to do from our clients. I want that 20% of the jobs go to John, 50% for Ashley and 30% to Mark and for that I'm trying to build a Google Sheets that randomly select according to those weights (20%, 50% and 30%). You can see it in [this google sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uOX6-ZjSdDrBYt-xGbn556VAU7Eok24wG-bz1vpxTmM/edit#gid=0).

The way I found seemed good at first, the problem is that it uses RANDBETWEEN function, and it keeps randomizing everytime anything happens in the sheet, so it might look like this:

[image]

And if I simply add one row it changes completely:

[image]

Is there a way to fix the randomization (maybe copy-pasting values through script?) or an alternative way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script, and use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to achieve the randomness. Unlike `RANDBETWEEN`, this won't refresh every time the sheet is edited, or even when the spreadsheet itself is refreshed. It also wouldn't require the data in `A6:B16` (the people and percentages from `A2:B4` would be enough).

To accomplish this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function GET_RANDOM_PERSON(values) { // "A2:B4"
  const random = Math.random(); // Random number between 0 and 1
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Change range if needed. Range could be a function argument if preferred:
  if (!values) values = sheet.getRange("A2:B4").getValues();
  let acc = 0;
  values = values.map(value => {
    acc = acc + value[1];
    return [value[0], acc]; // Return accumulated probabilities
  });
  // Return person getting the job:
  return values.find(value => value[1] > random)[0];
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function as if you were using a regular sheets formula, as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: That's of great help! Can we set the people and %s to be selectable in the sheet as a regular function?

Comment: @abutremutante I modified my code sample so that the function accepts a range as argument, like `=GET_RANDOM_PERSON(A2:B4)`. I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: shouldnt this `if (!values) values = sheet.getRange("A2:B4").getValues()` be changed too?

Comment: @abutremutante I added this so that there is a default range of input values in case no argument is provided. You can remove that line if you don't want to have a default range.

Answer (score 1):

With your current formula and setup, and without scripts, you can do it with iterative calculation:

1. Turn on Iterative Calculation: File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation
2. Make a tickbox. (I will use cell F2)
3. Change your formulas to look like this:

```
=IF($F$2;
  vlookup(RANDBETWEEN(1;10);$A$6:$B$16;2;0);
E2)
```

If checked, the cells will calculate new randoms on change. If unchecked, it will prevent any changes until checked again. (Checked = unlocked).

When you first enter the formula, it will initialize to 0. Check the box to generate the first list.